# Arrange column alphabetically in tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have:

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c("A","b","B","C","c"))
```

I want:

[image]

But when I try using arrange and tidyverse, I get:

```
> df %>% arrange(col1)
  col1
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    b
5    c
```

Comment: can you provide sessioninfo?

Comment: docker rocker/verse, first line is `FROM rocker/verse`

Comment: One hack-ish way would be to try `df %>% arrange(str_to_upper(col1))`. The reason they are ordering with capital and then lowercase is that the function is using the ASCII values which are numeric

Comment: is it only regarding rocker? 
my tidyverse is giving me proper output

Comment: if it is rocker issue, made hacky way. changed value of one cell to uppercase, did arrange, and then converted to orginal value. thanks @rkabuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```r
library(dplyr)

data.frame(col1 = c("A","b","B","C","c")) %>% 
  arrange(tolower(col1), col1)
#>   col1
#> 1    A
#> 2    B
#> 3    b
#> 4    C
#> 5    c
```

Comment: unfortunately it shows `b B` and then `C c`, I would like them to go `B b C c`

Comment: Try `df %>% arrange(col1) %>% arrange(tolower(col1))` - this will give you the output you want

Comment: @frank i see you have a solution, but i modified this one to show that you can use `col1` in `arrange()` twice to return the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This output will order the columns alphabetically, with capitalized entries coming first:

```
df %>%
  arrange(col1) %>%
  arrange(tolower(col1))

#>   col1
#> 1    A
#> 2    B
#> 3    b
#> 4    C
#> 5    c
```